# Angular why my boolean in service isn't updating in html?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using stepper for my project and I simply want to show/hide div based on the chosen product, but when I am trying to update on click on done() function it isnt updating in html

**.service**

```
 public beneficiary = true;
  public children = true;
  changeProduct() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("product") === 'ci') {
      this.beneficiary = false;
      }
    if (localStorage.getItem("product") === 'life') {
      this.children = false;
      }
  }
```

**.parent**

```
constructor(public stepService: StepService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.stepService.changeProduct();
   }
```

**parent.html**

```
<div class="filled" *ngIf="stepService.children">
...
</div>

<div class="filled" *ngIf="stepService.beneficiary">
...
</div>
```

**.child**

```
  done(index: number) {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.stepService.changeProduct();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upate your method like this

```
changeProduct() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("product") === 'ci') {
      this.beneficiary = false;
      this.children = true;
      }
    if (localStorage.getItem("product") === 'life') {
      this.beneficiary = true;
      this.children = false;
      }
```